# Discrete time Gronwall lemma

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

Consider a sequence $(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of non-negative real numbers and $(b_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ a positive sequence tending to zero as $i\to\infty$. Furthermore, suppose that there is a $c>0$ such that $$ a_i\geq b_i + ca_{i-1}.$$

I try to get a lower bound on $a_i$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and hoped to find a Gronwall type lemma but did not succeed. What quite obviously holds is $$a_i\geq b_i+c(b_{i-1} +c(b_{i-2}+c(...)))$$

and what also follows directly is the lower bound $a_i\geq c^i$ by omitting all the $b_i$. But I want to find a lower bound that depends on the $b_i$. How can I compute the extended right hand side or is there some lemma I could use?

Comment: Your estimate can be written as $a_i \ge b_i + cb_{i-1} + \ldots + c^{i-1}b_1 + c^i a_0$. I don't know if much more can be said unless you know more about the $(b_i)$. What kind of estimate are you looking for?

Comment: I hoped to get something better than the estimate, which I stated. The estimate I am hoping to get is an asymptotic one, e.g., $a_i\sim f(b_i,...,b_1)c^i$ for some function $f$. Additionally, we can assume that the $b_i$ are decreasing in $i$ if that helps.